# Django login with Allauth and an extended customer user model doesn’t seem to allow for email and password login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Hey guys so basically I’m implementing a custom user model extending from AbstractUser. I am also using Allauth. 
In previous practice projects I have built I am able to configure Allauth so that I can register new users and login in with only an email and password. This however is implemented without actually extending my user model(I just created the class and the passed). When I do then add custom fields for my users with my current project, and after reading the docs for Allauth about [custom user models](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models), I loose that functionality. I have to login with a username.

What I would like is to have my login how it works when you don’t extend the user model. Meaning that you can register and login in with you email and password. I have tried all the combinations I can think of using the settings in Allauth docs. I just cant seem to figure it out. Has anyone had a similar experience or just know perhaps what im doing wrong?

Comment: Ok so an update, I manage to sort of fix the issue...
When using the stander sign up and login forms I created it works perfectly and how it should, however, when adding a user from the admin or when loggin in through the admin login page it still asks for username and not email. I will keep trying but if anyone has any advice, that would be awesome.